# Error can't adapt type 'some.model.'

Tags: orm, odoo, odoo-9

I have error when try to receive data from column.
Model is:

```
class int_filial_phone(models.Model):
    _name = 'pr_filials.int_filial_phone'

    name = fields.Char(string="Partner-number") #,  compute='_get_name_field')
    number = fields.Char(string="Phone")
    active = fields.Boolean(string="Active")
    filial_addr_ids = fields.One2many('pr_filials.filial_addr', 'int_filial_phone_id', string='Address')
    filial_id = fields.Many2one('res.company',  string='Filial')
    advert_phone_ids = fields.One2many('pr_filials.advert_phone', 'int_filial_phone_id', 'Advert phone')

    _sql_constraints = [
        ('number_unique',
         'UNIQUE(number)',
         "The parameter number must be unique"),
    ]
```

Methods:

```
def find_client_in_filial_phone(self, phone, table):
        cr, uid, context, registry = request.cr, request.uid, request.context, request.registry
        result = None
        table = request.env[table]
        phone = self.format_symbol_phone(phone)
        _logger.error('find_client_in_filial_phone phone: %r ', phone )
        ids = table.sudo().search([['number', '=', phone],], limit=1)
        if(len(ids)>0):
            result = table.sudo().browse(ids)[0]
        _logger.error('find_client_in_filial_phone result: %r ', result )
        return result
```

I try to receive record id:

```
int_phone = self.find_client_in_filial_phone(data[3], 'pr_filials.int_filial_phone')
int_phone_id = int(int_phone.id)
```

All work fine
When i try to receive another field of record:

```
_logger.error("PHONE NAME: %r", int_phone[0].name)
```

I receive error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/home/skif/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 648, in _handle_exception
>       return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)   File "/home/skif/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 685, in dispatch
>       result = self._call_function(**self.params)   File "/home/skif/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 321, in _call_function
>       return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)   File "/home/skif/odoo/openerp/service/model.py", line 118, in wrapper
>       return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)   File "/home/skif/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 314, in checked_call
>       result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)   File "/home/skif/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 964, in **call**
>       return self.method(*args, **kw)   File "/home/skif/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 514, in response_wrap
>       response = f(*args, **kw)   File "/home/skif/odoo/openerp/my-addons/pr_finance/controllers/controllers.py",
>   line 151, in upload_file
>       _logger.error("PHONE INT : %r", int_phone[0].name)   File "/home/skif/odoo/openerp/fields.py", line 830, in **get**
>       self.determine_value(record)   File "/home/skif/odoo/openerp/fields.py", line 930, in determine_value
>       record._prefetch_field(self)   File "/home/skif/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 248, in wrapper
>       return new_api(self, *args, **kwargs)   File "/home/skif/odoo/openerp/models.py", line 3308, in _prefetch_field
>       result = records.read([f.name for f in fs], load='_classic_write')   File "/home/skif/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 248, in wrapper
>       return new_api(self, *args, **kwargs)   File "/home/skif/odoo/openerp/models.py", line 3238, in read
>       self._read_from_database(stored, inherited)   File "/home/skif/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 248, in wrapper
>       return new_api(self, *args, **kwargs)   File "/home/skif/odoo/openerp/models.py", line 3376, in _read_from_database
>       cr.execute(query_str, params)   File "/home/skif/odoo/openerp/sql_db.py", line 141, in wrapper
>       return f(self, *args, **kwargs)   File "/home/skif/odoo/openerp/sql_db.py", line 220, in execute
>       res = self._obj.execute(query, params)   File "/home/skif/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/extensions.py",
>   line 129, in getquoted
>       pobjs = [adapt(o) for o in self._seq] ProgrammingError: can't adapt type 'pr_filials.int_filial_phone'

How I can receive data from record? Why i received id but cannot received data from other fields of record?

Comment: edit you question and add the method that generate the error and don't put the error log inside a quote by make code so we can see the error source

Comment: I modified.
After calling find_client_in_filial_phone I must receive recordset model int_filial_phone. And when Itry to receive ID field of this record - all fine(int_phone.id). When I try to receive another field this record (for example int_phone.name) I receive error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the new version of the api, when you used the method "search", the value return is a recordSet.

Example:

Old api version

```
record_ids = self.pool.get('model.name').search([('name', '=', 'Jon doe')])
# The value of record_ids is like [1,2,3,4]
records = self.pool.get('model.name').browse(records_ids)
# The value of records is like model.name(1,2,3,4)
```

In the new version of api

```
records = self.env['model.name'].search([('name', '=', 'Jondoe')])
# The vale of records is like model.name(1,2,3,4)
```

In your code you try to browse with recordSet.

```
def find_client_in_filial_phone(self, phone, table):
    ...
    ids = table.sudo().search([['number', '=', phone],], limit=1)
    # Here ids is a recordSet
    if(len(ids)>0):
        result = table.sudo().browse(ids)[0]
    _logger.error('find_client_in_filial_phone result: %r ', result )
    return result
```

You must do like this.

```
def find_client_in_filial_phone(self, phone, table):
    cr, uid, context, registry = request.cr, request.uid, request.context, request.registry
    table = request.env[table]
    phone = self.format_symbol_phone(phone)
    _logger.error('find_client_in_filial_phone phone: %r ', phone )
    result = table.sudo().search([['number', '=', phone],], limit=1)
    _logger.error('find_client_in_filial_phone result: %r ', result )
    return result
```

If your search doesn't find value, an empty recordSet is return.